# Powershell scheduled task reporting - change status from number to word

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have this powershell code that gets any scheduled tasks that don't have an error code of 0 and have a status of 'Ready':

```
Get-ScheduledTask | Select-Object  @{Name="Task Name";Expression={$_.Path}}, LastRunTime, NextRunTime, LastTaskResult, State | Where-Object   {($_.LastTaskResult -NE '0') -AND ($_.State -LIKE '3') }
```

Here is an output example:

```
Task Name      : \UserScheduleTaskNet4
LastRunTime    : 21/04/2017 15:25:00
NextRunTime    : 21/04/2017 15:30:00
LastTaskResult : 267009
State          : 4
```

I would like the state to output as the word rather than the number - in this case the state '4' would output as 'Running'.

I have this snippet of code, but am not sure how to implement it into my `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
 New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{ 
                    'Name' = $_.name 
                    'Path' = $_.path 
                    'State' = switch ($_.State) { 
                        0 {'Unknown'} 
                        1 {'Disabled'} 
                        2 {'Queued'} 
                        3 {'Ready'} 
                        4 {'Running'} 
                   Default {'Unknown'} 
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$states=@('Unknown','Disabled','Queued','Ready','Running')
Get-ScheduledTask | 
   Where-Object   {($_.LastTaskResult -NE '0') -AND ($_.State -LIKE '3') } |
   Select-Object  @{Name="Task Name";Expression={$_.Path}}, LastRunTime, NextRunTime, LastTaskResult, @{name='State';expression={$states[$_.state]}}
```

You can specify your states as either enum or object with key-value pairs, then get its field from supplied field. Be warned that if you'd encounter an unexpected `state`, the column would have a null instead of raw state value. In your case, `$states` can be a simple 0-based array, since your enum isn't hollow and starts from 0.

Comment: Thanks - can I just check something...I see you have put the `where-object` cmdlet before the `select-object` cmdlet, is that just better practice or will it make a difference to my results?

Comment: No difference largely, but if you place where after select, you can't filter by property you have not selected. Also it's better to first filter with where, then select, format etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple solution (I just had the same problem myself):

Convert to string!

```
 New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{ 
                    'Name' = $_.name 
                    'Path' = $_.path 
                    'State' = "$($_.State)" 
                    }
```

Or here is my version:

```
$taskHash = @{}
$array = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\XY\" | Select-Object TaskName,State
foreach($entry in $array){
    $taskHash[$entry.TaskName] = "$($entry.State)"
}
```